getting error :ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.66' in python
#calculation of daily calorie needed in women 
weight = float(input("please enter your weight in kg: \n" )) 
height = int(input(" please enter your height : \n"))
age = input(" please enter your age :\n")
activity_level = input(" please enter your activity level : ( lightly active  , moderately active , very active ) \n" )
formula = 655.1 + (weight*9.563) + (height*1.850) - (age*4.676) 
lightly_active = formula*1.375
moderately_active = formula*1.55
very_active = formula*1.9
if activity_level == "lightly active" :
    print(lightly_active)
elif activity_level == "moderately active" :
    print(moderately_active)
else :
    print(very_active)

the code is about calculation of daily calorie needed in woman .
i have value error in line 2  (Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.66').
i could not solve it .

Why are you using int? Like the weight, you're entering height as a floating-point number.

You should try float instead.

Try to learn the difference between an int and a float.  An int is just an integer.  So why does int('1.66') give an error?  Because 1.66 is not a valid integer.  1 is an integer.  2 is an integer.  3 is an integer.  1.66 is not an integer.  You should be using float for this.  And why are you keeping age as a string?  That's another bug.  Make it a float as well.

As several commenters have said, the problem is in your data types. You have three different types in your program, some of which are probably not the best fit.

weight is a float. A float is a number with a decimal part, so this is a good type for a number representing numerical weight.
height is an int. An int is an integer (ie, a number with no decimal part). This is probably not ideal; from your data, it seems you want to be able to enter decimal heights, which is throwing an error since ints cannot have decimal parts. You should make this variable a float like weight.
age is a string. A string is a sequence of characters - it can contain the digits that make up a number, but it is not a number itself. That means you can't perform numerical operations (+, -, *, /, etc.) on a string. Make age an int or a float, depending on whether you want decimal ages to be allowed - this will let you use it in your formulas.
activity_level is a string. This is perfect for your use case.

With these changes, your program will look like this:
weight = float(input("please enter your weight in kg: \n" )) 
height = float(input(" please enter your height : \n")) # This should be a float
age = int(input(" please enter your age :\n")) # This should be an int (or a float)
activity_level = input(" please enter your activity level : ( lightly active  , moderately active , very active ) \n" )

formula = 655.1 + (weight*9.563) + (height*1.850) - (age*4.676) 
lightly_active = formula*1.375
moderately_active = formula*1.55
very_active = formula*1.9

if activity_level == "lightly active" :
    print(lightly_active)
elif activity_level == "moderately active" :
    print(moderately_active)
else :
    print(very_active)

